# chrome not reachable with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I have a python script, with selenium, that works fine most of the time. But sometimes, for an unknown reason, Chrome closes and the script keeps running but throwing an error for each action it tries to send to Chrome:

```
Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.71)
```

How can I catch that error and restart chrome in case of failure?

Thanks

Comment: Selenium requires that you have the driver for the browser you are using installed. Have you downloaded the Chrome web driver? https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Comment: Yes. I can use selenium. But just sometimes Chrome is closed unexpected and then the error appears